# How to put or embed a fully Ajax checkout form on WooCommerce single product page?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, checkbox

I’m using this code snippet to show WooCommerce checkout form on the single product page :

```
    add_filter('woocommerce_short_description','ts_add_text_short_descr');
function ts_add_text_short_descr($description){
  $text="[woocommerce_checkout]";
  return $description.$text;
}
```

It's working, But this form lacks the Ajax functionality.
Like when you click the 'pass order' button, the form doesn't submit using AJAX but redirect to check out page

So, how can I enable the AJAX functionality?

Comment: There are few ajax events that need to be triggered https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/342148/list-of-js-events-in-the-woocommerce-frontend. They check if you are on checkoutpage or not so in this case they wont trigger so start from there .

Comment: This is not an easy tasks. There are few free plugins that do that so you can preview the code there if you insist on writing your own just to get the idea how to do it.